# Python - Glob to recursively dig through directories

Tags: python, glob

I currently have a directory structure as follows:

```
/Users/user/dir/image.png
/Users/user/dir/sample.txt
/Users/user/dir/nested_dir/dir/dir/file.txt
/Users/user/dir/nested_dir1/dir2/dir3/file2.txt
```

My objective is to recursively dig inside each directory all the way to fetch particular files that I need. The issue is that I also want to capture 'image.png' as well as any other file type that is not a directory while also performing the recursive searching.

Here is what I currently have:

```
for file in Path('/Users/user/dir').glob('**/'):
        print(f'file:{file}')
```

this then produces every single file and folder all the way to the end, however the items that are not directories are not showing (image.py, sample.txt). I want to capture those as well for later. Suggestions?

Additionally, I have tried the following:

```
for file in Path('/Users/user/dir').glob('*/'):
```

And this does in fact give me the items im asking for, however the nested recursion is not working, just gives me the top level directory.

Comment: Have you tried using `os.walk`? That will separate out the files from the directories for you, as well as doing the recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`**/*`** as a pattern:

> ```py
> >>> from pprint import pprint as pp
> >>> import pathlib as pl
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> p = pl.Path(".")
> >>>
> >>> old_way = list(p.glob("**/"))  # Your way
> >>> pp(old_way)
> [WindowsPath('.'),
>  WindowsPath('dir0'),
>  WindowsPath('dir1'),
>  WindowsPath('dir1/dir10')]
> >>>
> >>> new_way = list(p.glob("**/*"))
> >>> pp(new_way)
> [WindowsPath('dir0'),
>  WindowsPath('dir1'),
>  WindowsPath('file0.txt'),
>  WindowsPath('dir0/file00.txt'),
>  WindowsPath('dir1/dir10'),
>  WindowsPath('dir1/file10.txt')]
> >>>
> >>> newer_way = [p] + list(p.glob("**/*"))  # Prepend globed dir
> >>> pp(newer_way)
> [WindowsPath('.'),
>  WindowsPath('dir0'),
>  WindowsPath('dir1'),
>  WindowsPath('file0.txt'),
>  WindowsPath('dir0/file00.txt'),
>  WindowsPath('dir1/dir10'),
>  WindowsPath('dir1/file10.txt')]
> ```

Here's [[Python.Docs]: pathlib - Path.glob(pattern)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) for reference.

Comment: Turns out, I actually need the parent directory (as shown in the 'your way' section as the first item). How do I incorporate your way above which works great, however I would like to also have a look at the directory im globbing for?

Comment: Just prepend the current path to the list. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk):

```
import os

all_files = []

for root, subdirs, files in os.walk("/Users/user/dir"):
    all_files += [os.path.join(root, file) for file in files]

print(all_files)
```

Comment: This might be an adequate workaround, but `glob` is supposed to be able to do this on its own.