Run all jupyter notebooks inside folder and subfolders in an ordered manner and displaying process
I want to run (in an alphabetical order, not in parallel) all jupyter notebooks inside a folder that contain many subfolders.

Each subfolder may contain other folders.
Folders contain jupyter notebooks and the resulting outcome (csv, json, excel, jpg files).
It is important that files run in order, since the outcome of one notebook is used by others as input source.

As jupyter notebooks are executed, I would like the see a print stating the jupyter notebook and the path.
Until now I would create a jupyter notebook inside each folder, and run inside all the jupyter notebooks from the same folder using %run samplenotebook1.ipynb. However, this becomes tedious when there are numerous folders and subfolders and thus I need to speed up.
I have tried the solution from this post, the notebook seems to be running but if I open any of the folders where jupyter notebooks are supposed to run, I cannot see any file generated from running the jupyter notebooks.
Code below is the one I used, but the result was not the desired one.
import papermill as pm
from glob import glob

for nb in glob('*.ipynb'):
    pm.execute_notebook(
        input_path=nb,
        output_path=nb,
        engine_name='embedded',
    )

I  have also tried code below, I get a print as if it were done, but it only runs notebooks in the folder, not in subfolders.
import papermill as pm
from pathlib import Path

for nb in Path('../').glob('*.ipynb'):
    pm.execute_notebook(
        input_path=nb,
        output_path=nb  # Path to save executed notebook
    )
print ('done')

Code above will run jupyter notebooks from the path, but not from inner folders. I tried adding /* in the path, but it would not work.

I'm not familiar with "engine_name='embedded',". That may be causing you different things than you expect. Are you using ploomber in this? I'm not familiar with using that either. I would run some notebooks the more typical/more direct way via papermill only, using the command line interface. Hardcode a few things first and then you make it programmatic later. Also, jupytext can run notebooks on the command line. But I believe it runs the entire notebook before saving the notebook and so often folks don't want that to monitor progress. Here, it seems you're monitoring progress by the ...

 associated files your notebooks would make and so it may be suitable. Papermill on the command line will edit the notebook as it runs and so you get better feedback during the run. I wonder if the API does things differently and that is why you aren't see things during processing. Or plommber does. Several things strike me about this part of your post: "However, this becomes tedious when there are numerous folders and subfolders and thus I need to speed up." If you want this process to be sped up though, you'd want to remove notebooks from this and use pure Python as much as ...

 possible. Or probably even better because you could stick with notebooks, you may want something like Snakemake that will analyze at the outset what you need to make and only make that. For example, since your code needs to run in alphabetical order, if you change a notebook far down the chain, you don't want it to have to run all the earlier notebooks in the pipeline. Snakemake will see what got edited and only re-run the parts necessary to get the output pertinent or downstream of that. Of course, then you need to learn Snakemake and it can be a bit daunting. However, if ...

 you've already tracked what associated files you expect produced from most of your notebooks, maybe I could help you with converting running, say the first three of them, to snakemake, and you can see the logic involved and code the rest. Snakemake is a superset of Python so if you know a little Python you can be a superuser pretty fast.

Not an expert in jupyter, but why your input and output paths match?

@alko input and output paths do not need to match, simply output of a jupyter notebook are saved in the same folder where it is run. Then an output is used as input for another jupyter notebook, either in the same or in anohter folder

I was talking about input and output only in regards to using Snakemake. You basically tell it targets to make and then in the recipes (called 'rules') you describe how to make those with what input. ....Now back to what you are doing now.... So for your bottom code, Path('../').glob('*.ipynb'), we should be able to make that into print statement and it will tell you what is in the list. The print statement is: print(list(Path('../').glob('*.ipynb'))) Same with first one but that one is similar, did you run print(glob('*.ipynb')) and the one I put above & see what it said?

 I'm worried you have things in subfolder and aren't accounting for that. The examples you reference are only concerned with a single directory. Each command I see you've tried only globs one folder and is not recursive. The first one, glob('*.ipynb') makes a list from all the matching .ipynb files in the directory where the notebook is or what your current working directory is set to in the notebook, via %cd. The other, (Path('../').glob('*.ipynb'), check one level up from where it is run and also is not recursive.

Sorry, I had misread the note about input and output being from josephmaria. Nevermind about that part. Sorry. .... Anyway, you second code block works great for the notebooks in the directory where it is run if you change the code to  for nb in Path('.').glob('*.ipynb').  In the indented code, before the pm.execute_notebook line, I put print(f"Processing {nb}...") to get better feedback. I got Processing testnb1.ipynb... and then I got a nice progress bar as it ran. When I opened testnb1.ipynb. up, I could see the code had run. (I had cleared it out beforehand and closed it.)

@Wayne thanks for your comments. Can you please suggest me how to adapt existing code to make it recursive, so that it runs all notebooks inside inner folders?

Posted in an answer so that I can format it. Do you need the alphabetical to take into account the directory and subdirectories or just the notebook name?

Seems the main thing you needed to change was to make the glob collecting the notebook names recursive so that it looked in subdirectories.
This doesn't do alphabetical (yet), but does all notebooks as you asked in your latest comment:
# For recursive running of each notebook`Path('.').glob('**/*.ipynb')`, based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/64162840/8508004
import papermill as pm
from pathlib import Path

for nb in Path('.').glob('**/*.ipynb'):
    print(f"Processing {nb}...")
    if 'Untitled' not in str(nb):
        pm.execute_notebook(
            input_path=nb,
            output_path=nb  # Path to save executed notebook
        )
print ('done')


If you need to specify order, you'd sort the results of the glob() by your preference.
You'll most likely want/need to convert it to a list object for this. (One way would be to typecase it list(Path('.').glob('**/*.ipynb')).) Something like this to combine this sorting with iterating on the sorted list as a replacement for nb in Path('.').glob('**/*.ipynb')::
notebooks_to_be_run = Path('.').glob('**/*.ipynb')
notebooks_to_be_run_ordered = sorted([str(x) for x in notebooks_to_be_run], key=str.casefold)
for nb in notebooks_to_be_run_ordered:

That code includes the entire path in the sort and so it may not be what you want, but may work for those with only notebooks in one or two directories, especially if you add in , reverse=True after key=str.casefold.
key=str.casefold comes from here. You'd want to leave that out if you want to go by case with uppercase coming before names that begin with lowercase.
If you file names involve numbers, you may be interested in the drop-in replacement for sorted() that is natsort.sorted(), see here and here.
natsort.sorted() works with key=str.casefold, too.
I probably should add that if your notebook list is going to be predictable/and or you need an order that is just so custom that it is hard to code, you can use the result of notebooks_to_be_run to hand-edit and make the list notebooks_to_be_run_ordered have the exact order you want. Example, imagine notebooks_to_be_run gives ["a.ipynb", "b.ipynb", "c.ipynb"] and for whatever reason you'd like c, then a, and then b run. Just before the line for nb in notebooks_to_be_run_ordered: you can assign the order in the list you want to 'hard code' the specified order, replacing the for loop-initiating line like so:
notebooks_to_be_run_ordered = ["c.ipynb", "a.ipynb", "b.ipynb"]
for nb in notebooks_to_be_run_ordered:

That would be tedious if you have a lot with long paths, but it is doable. And if it changes often, you could even imagine making a widget that runs prior to the for loop that lets you sort the list as you wish.

One reason I like Jupytext for running notebooks is that Papermill will sometimes add cruft directly into your notebooks. And so if you find that annoying, you can substitute in the use of Jupytext for the step to execute the notebooks.

are files processed in order of appearance in the folder?

I just asked you a comment on that above. I'm not following how they actually look because you never provided an outline of your hierarchy and notebook names? It is common to provide a tree showing that for such a question, see here. We don't have access to your machine so you are supposed to help us reproduce the issue in your post, see section 'Help others reproduce the problem' in How do I ask a good question?.

I cannot provide a hierarchy of folders, since each subfolder may have different subfolders.

I still need to know what you mean then by alpahbetical? Just the notebook name? First letter?

you are right. Alphabetical is not the most accurate word. I apologize. I meant simply that notebooks need to be run  in order of appeance inside the folder and subfolders.

You mean there is only one notebook in each folder? Then the subfolder in that one has one notebook? Or does a directory have more than one notebook and if so what is 'appearance' based on in your view? Different people sort their directories different.

"inside a folder that contain many subfolders." is what the question states.

Yes. But please consider that doesn't imply any order to those without access to your system. We don't need you to share your actual hierarchy. Typically, you would share something about the file tree in the post. And you could say it 'looks something like this' and give your expectations.
